# Is there a way to to tune parameters inside a recipe workflow?

Tags: r, tidymodels, recipe

I'd like to use the `step_impute_knn` function from the `recipe` package to impute some missing values in my data. I've tested it with the default parameters (neighbours = 5, nthread = 1 and eps = 1e-08) and can see that the resulting means and standard deviations for numerical variables (for example) are fairly close to the original data after imputation.

I'd like, however, to tune these parameters to see if there is an optimal set but I don't even know how to start inside the recipe package. The answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62979746/tidymodels-tuning-recipe-parameters) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67991125/how-to-tune-a-tidymodels-recipe-parameter) are too complex or specific for me to understand.

The function `step_impute_knn` doesn't provide any tuning options, as far as I can see and I'd rather not do it manually. Is there a simple way to do this?

Sample data:

```
train <- structure(list(PassengerId = c("0001_01", "0002_01", "0003_01", 
"0003_02", "0004_01", "0005_01"), HomePlanet = c("Europa", "Earth", 
"Europa", "Europa", "Earth", NA), CryoSleep = c("False", 
"False", "False", "False", "False", "False"), Cabin = c("B/0/P", 
"F/0/S", "A/0/S", "A/0/S", "F/1/S", "F/0/P"), Destination = c("TRAPPIST-1e", 
"TRAPPIST-1e", "TRAPPIST-1e", "TRAPPIST-1e", "TRAPPIST-1e", "PSO J318.5-22"
), Age = c(39, 24, 58, 33, 16, 44), VIP = c("False", "False", 
"True", "False", "False", "False"), RoomService = c(0, 109, 43, 
0, 303, 0), FoodCourt = c(0, 9, 3576, 1283, 70, 483), ShoppingMall = c(0, 
25, 0, 371, 151, 0), Spa = c(0, 549, 6715, 3329, 565, 291), VRDeck = c(0, 
44, 49, 193, 2, 0), Name = c("Maham Ofracculy", "Juanna Vines", 
"Altark Susent", "Solam Susent", "Willy Santantines", "Sandie Hinetthews"
), Transported = c("False", "True", "False", "False", "True", 
"True")), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

What I have so far:

```
train_no_na <- train %>%
na.omit()

imp_knn_blueprint <- recipe(Transported ~ ., data = train_no_na) %>%
     step_impute_knn(recipe = ., HomePlanet, 
              impute_with = imp_vars(.), neighbors = 5, 
              options = list(nthread = 1, eps = 1e-08))

imp_knn_prep <- prep(imp_knn_blueprint, training = train_no_na)
imp_knn_5 <- bake(imp_knn_prep, new_data = train)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can (although we don't consider `nthread` or `eps` tuning parameters).

You would give them a value of `tune()` in the recipe and treat it like any other tuning parameter associated with the model.

You would use `tune_grid()` or one of the other tuning parameter functions. tidymodels even understands what this particular parameter is and has built-in default ranges (although you can pick the gird yourself)

There's an example of tuning recipe parameters in the [tidymodels book](https://www.tmwr.org/grid-search#evaluating-grid) and also on the `tune_grid` help page (in the [examples](https://tune.tidymodels.org//reference/tune_grid.html#ref-examples)).

Comment: Nice, it definitely looks easier to follow. I'll try it tomorrow and mark the answer if I succeed.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot make the above work with what I want to do. In order to tune the knn-model, I'd have to use the `nearest_neighbor` engine from the parsnip package and that one doesn't have the option of predicting mixed parameters, as far as I can see. 

I still want to use the Gower-distance for the imputed values but that would require either creating my own function or finding some other package...